# How to rapidly copy a field into another in a very big table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm doing a simple

```
UPDATE table SET field2 = field1
```

but I ve about 100 db like this and in each DB, this table is at minimum 1 milion of records, up to 15 M, and ALL of these DB are on the same instance of SQL SERVER, so to avoid to kill the machine I'm running over a db at time.

very time consuming

Actually to update only 9,499,130 rows It took over 42 minutes.

I'm simply hoping there is something to do to speed up it.

.. chunking .. ? Indexes ? I'm really asking for idea or best pratictice or whatelse.

Use comments to ask me for info if needed. I'll reply soon.

NB: I'll accept even single-word 'NO' answers.

EDIT: this is **not a course exercise**. I'm simply maintaining something not created by myself

EDIT 2: We're doing this update because the **100% of records have this fields different**

EDIT 3: I already verified that **no triggers** are setted on the table.

EDIT 4: the **reason** of the slowness is due to very very bad windows 2008 server VPS, the **disk bandwidth is the worst I've ever seen** !

Comment: are there any triggers on that tables You update?

Comment: Drop nonclustered indexes that reference Field2, run update in chunks, recreate indexes. Add a where clause to limit the updates taking place `WHERE Field2 <> Field1`.  This is very much a horse for courses exercise, and there is no one correct way of doing it. You will just need to try different things and see what works best for you.

Comment: It's not a courses exercise, it's a real life example of what happens when someone leaves a  company and a 'newbie' take its place :)

Comment: No, there  are no trigger. I'll check next monday for the presence of an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If field2 is used in an index, you should disable index on that table. Then perform your update. Once that's done, reenable the index.

Comment: That's could be very usefull ... how can I 'disable' an index? Drop an recreating it?

Comment: To disable an index, ALTER INDEX [myindexname] ON mytablename DISABLE
To reenable the index, ALTER INDEX [myindexname] ON mytablename REBUILD